# What is the correct way to use WaitForSeconds(); in an IEnumerator function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, ienumerator

So I'm trying to make a tower defense game. This code section is supposed to make a text change slowly to look something like this;

Get ready for a new wave!
Wave Incoming.
Wave Incoming..
Wave Incoming...
Wave 0

Currently, what happens is as soon as I begin the wave, the dots just rapidly go by and just immediately change to "Wave 0" I've tried changing the float in WaitForSeconds(); and nothing works. How do I use this correctly, so it waits one second before every change of strings.

```
    IEnumerator waveIncomingText()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    yield return waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming.";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    yield return waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming..";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    yield return waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming...";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    yield return waveNumberText.text = "Wave " + waveIndex.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are numerous examples of correct usage of `WaitForSeconds()`, here on Stack Overflow as well as in the documentation itself. See duplicates for a few of those examples.

Comment: I pretty much doubt your code does even compile ...

Comment: If you find yourself writing `for(var i ... switch(i)....` then the loop is completely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);` instead of putting the `yield return` on the other statement.

```
    IEnumerator waveIncomingText()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming.";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming..";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    waveNumberText.text = "Wave Incoming...";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                    waveNumberText.text = "Wave " + waveIndex.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        
        }
    }
```

For more details, see docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

---

### Edit:

Additional help for your multiple coroutine problem in comments below:

Looking at this part of your code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (countdown <= 5)
    {
        StartCoroutine(waveIncomingText());
    }
    
    ...
    
    countdown -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Update is called every frame. So every frame you are checking if `countdown <= 5` and if so, starting a coroutine. This means that after this monobehavior has been active for 5 seconds, *every frame it is going to start a coroutine*.

Clearly this isn't your intention, so we need a way only trigger this code path once. This can be done using something like this:

```
private bool showIncomingWaveText = true;
void Update()
{
    if (showIncomingWaveText && countdown <= 5)
    {
        showIncomingWaveText = false;
        StartCoroutine(waveIncomingText());
    }
```

Then when you reset the wave, you can also reset the `showIncomingWaveText` variable.

Comment: still quite redundant code ;) the `WaitForSeconds` could be before the `switch` since it is anyway done for all cases. case 1-3 are basically redundant and you could combine these.

Comment: Of course. But that was not the question.

Comment: I am new to unity c# I used to program in lua, then switched to c#. I am used to the built in "wait()" function in lua, you could imagine how often that is used so I'm having a bit of trouble getting used to it. I used the correct syntax for "WaitForSeconds" and put it before the switch statement, but now the text is very glitchy.[Glitchy text](https://gyazo.com/2178623cb2daad522a3bd04c6685c1a6)  [Full code](https://pastebin.com/kpirWQGi)

Comment: @Ol'yelir you are probably running multiple Coroutines parallel since you start new ones from `Update` ...

Comment: @derHugo Oh, I understand now, but how would you reccomend I go about starting a coroutine? I tried getting rid of the for loop and replacing "i" with "countdown", and it just doesn't run at all.

Comment: @Ol'yelir I updated the answer with some help for your coroutine problem.